# How do I efficiently check if an integer is not in a massive array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, iterator, runtime-error

I'm working on an assignment where I have to find the smallest positive integer greater than 0 that is NOT within a huge array including 100,000 elements. I'm able to do it so it's correct but apparently my solution takes way too long and returns a timeout error.

this is my current solution:

```
function solution(A) {
    let min=1

    while(A.includes(min) === true){
        min++
    }

    return min
}
```

Is there a faster way of doing this that doesn't involve looping through every single element?

edit: whoops guys I forgot a key element to this question!

edit 2: the minimum value would be -2 and the maximum value would be 100,000 and they are not in order

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Your question title and the actual question itself are two different tasks.

Comment: @Terry, he just edited the question, that is why.

Comment: how big are the values, what is the max value?

Comment: Are you sure that the given array isn't sorted from the beginning?

Comment: yes it's specifically shuffled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object and add each wanted value to the object.

Then take the smallest key and check if is is equal to one and increment until no key is found. Otherwise return one.

```js
function getSmallest(array) {
    let temp = Object.create(null),
        smallest;

    for (const v of array) if (v > 0) temp[v] = true;
    smallest = +Object.keys(temp)[0];

    if (smallest !== 1) return 1;

    while (temp[++smallest]);

    return smallest;
}

console.log(getSmallest([2, 1, 0])); // 3
console.log(getSmallest([2, 3, 0])); // 1
```

Comment: Oh, you beat me by 1 minute I think, was going to post an answer similar to this. I used -3 as the smallest number, is the only difference I think. You're Genius!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work actually, because when I add 1 to the array it returns 0, which it can't do.

Comment: @JordanForbes, which value would be the wanted result in this case?

Comment: it would be the smallest positive integer greater than 0 that isn't in the array. So if I added 1 into the array then the answer I'd want is 5

Comment: what does the "smallest" term you put after the comma do?

Comment: which comma? where?

Comment: also, this works perfectly so thank you, but now I'm just trying to figure out why it works.

Comment: let temp = Object.create(null),smallest;

Comment: it is a declaration of the variable.

Comment: oh, is that just a different way of declaring smallest as an empty variable?

Comment: @NinaScholz doesn't `Object.keys( temp )` perform a sort of the numeric keys of `temp` making this algorithm essentially O(n log n) rather than O(n)?

Comment: @JonTrent, maybe, but i have not stated any big o. the dvantage of an object with index like keys is the standard sorting of these keys.

Comment: @NinaScholz I realize that you have not stated a big O advantage, but performance is central to the question...  Simply Array.sort() and then walking the array will be O(n log n).  If Object.keys() is essentially a sort ( and am not sure if the keys are sorted on insert or during Object.keys(), but typical sort of random values is O(n log n)) then there is no advantage to the complexity of the solution.  Seems like mapping the input Array to another Array, a Set, or avoiding Object.keys() (assuming sort of keys does not occur during object key insertion) will result in a solution of O(n), no?

Comment: @JonTrent, i think it is inserting like an array for index like keys, so no sorting takes place, just the same as for addressing indices of an array.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe this is a test to see if you know search algorithms for an unsorted array. Have you been taught about binary search?

Comment: yeah but it's been quite a long time.

Comment: For using this concept, the array needs to be sorted.

Comment: so would that involve sorting it into, say, a heap, then searching through that?

Comment: Binary search, you break the entire array into 2 parts, then perform some checks, then proceed with choosing any one part of the broken array, and then do the same with that part as well. And yes, sorting is required for that.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code for following statement: "Find minimal positive integer NOT in array of numbers that could be any from -2 to 10000".

```
const arr = [5,4,6,7,5,6,4,5];
const p = new Array(10004);
arr.forEach(el => p[el + 2] = 1);
let answer = 10004;
for (let i = 3; i < 10004; ++i) {
  if (!p[i]) {
    answer = i - 2;
    console.log(answer);
    break;
  } else if (i == 10003) {
    console.log('no solution');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorting the array seems like a good place to start. Then you can loop or binary search from there to find your smallest positive integer.

Comment: how would I go about sorting it? Do you happen to know of a tutorial I can look at?

Comment: Sorting the array itself is going to be expensive.

Comment: @JordanForbes, do you think you can use inbuilt function for that? I mean are you allowed for doing so?

Comment: Sorting requires usually no less than O(N) time approximation. Its enough to one time go throuh array and find minimal.

Comment: My bad, I misread the title, find the smallest possible integer NOT in the array. Ignore my comment.

Comment: @Adam, no he edited it, after a while, previously it was what you read.

Comment: yeah haha the confusion is my fault sorry bout that